# $.ajax call throws error when browsing to another page before the request is done

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've encountered a problem in Firefox (does not happen in IE) where my Javascript kicks off a call to a service, which may take a little time to load. If the user navigates to another page before the call finishes, the `error` method of the `jQuery.ajax()` object is called.

I am looking for a way to either:

1. Not have the error thrown when the user browses to another page when the request hasn't finishes, OR
2. Have the error method distinguish between "real" errors and this error.

My error method, not surprisingly, shows the user an error, and I do not want to do this when the error is caused by navigating to another page.

My simple test code involves the following Javascript and a service that sleeps for 20 seconds then returns a string.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#testLink').click(function ()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Services/NU.Web.NUnet.Services.UserService.asmx/LongRunningService",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(xhr);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#testLink').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Services/NU.Web.NUnet.Services.UserService.asmx/LongRunningService",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(xhr);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (xhr.status === 500) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! The status is 0 when browsing to another page, so I'm checking against that value. This was a tricky one, because I couldn't see anything in Firebug because the page was reloading :x

Comment: Your welcome. You can use the "Persist" button in Firebug's console for these types of errors.